# How can I center a div vertically if the height of the container is unknown?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

How can I center the orange box in the remaining visible green area? if the main box is too big for (100vh - 20px * 2 - h of top bar) it should just use the minimum distance to top bar and end of container - here defined as margin.

```css
#container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#topBar {
  background-color: yellow;
  top: 0;
}

#mainBox {
  background-color: orange;
  margin: 20px 0;
}






body {
margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="topBar">Height of this is unknown!<br>.</div>
  <div id="mainBox">Height of this is also unknown. It should be vertically in the center of the REMAINING VISIBLE green area<br>.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flexbox to center. Something like that should be good

```css
#container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#topBar {
  background-color: yellow;
  top: 0;
}

#mainBox {
  background-color: orange;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

body {
margin: 0;
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="topBar">Height of this is unknown!<br>.</div>
  <div class="center">
  <div id="mainBox">Height of this is also unknown. It should be vertically in the center of the REMAINING VISIBLE green area<br>.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the height for the green container setting it to `auto`, which means that its height will be based on its content length.

```css
#container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#topBar {
  background-color: yellow;
  top: 0;
}

#mainBox {
  background-color: orange;
  margin: auto 0; /*Here is changed*/
}


body {
margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="topBar">Height of this is unknown!<br>.</div>
  <div id="mainBox">Height of this is also unknown. It should be vertically in the center of the REMAINING VISIBLE green area<br>.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: good idea! what if i still want to incorporate the minimum distance of 20px? I can just create a another wrapper?